# In my package.json file after installing node, I want to have a command that can automatically compile my any of my sass files using one command?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, node-sass, npm-scripts

So, to outline what I want, in my script i want to have only one command. So, I want to be able to pass an argument into the code I am running like so :

```
"scripts": {
"compile:'variable'": "node-sass sass/variable.scss css/variable.css -w" }
```

Is there a way to do something like this in npm so that I can pass an argument into my command that I would run? In the command line I would like to compile in a simple way. I would, say if I wanted to compile a file called "home". So, I want to be able to type into the command line :

```
npm run compile:home
```

Then, this, I would want to get the following command taken through the package.json and the running the node-sass to compile it:

```
"node-sass scss/home.scss css/home.css -w"
```

If you have any questions feel free to comment.

Comment: Some questions... **1.** Wil your source `.scss` file always exist in the `sass` folder? .  **2.** Will the resultant `.css` always be saved to the `css` folder? **3.** Should the `css/variable.scss` part actually be `css/variable.css` (i.e. a `.css` suffix instead of `.scss`)

Comment: Yes, this will always be like that because it is the way my app is structured. Yes, that was what I mean I'll edit the question to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `npm-scripts` has no built-in way to achieve your requirement in a way that runs successfully cross-platform.

However, a couple of ways to meet your requirement are as follows (...you probably want *Solution B*):

---

#### Solution A:

If you only have a few `.scss` file to compile to `.css` then the simplest solution would be to create a `npm-script` for each file. For example:

```json
"scripts": {
  "compile:home": "node-sass sass/home.scss css/home.css -w",
  "compile:quxx": "node-sass sass/quux.scss css/quxx.css -w"
}
```

This will allow you to run each script using the command syntax that you require, i.e.

```
$ npm run compile:home
$ npm run compile:quxx
```

However, this is *probably* not ideal, as I guess you have lots of `.scss` files - hence your question about utilizing a variable in the script.

---

#### Solution B:

A solution that works cross-platform, (and enables you to define the filename as an argument via the CLI), is to write a *nodejs* utility script. The *nodejs* script can then be invoked via the `scripts` section of your `package.json`.

The following provides the necessary steps to achieve this:

1. Create a nodejs script as follows: Let's name the file `sass-to-css.js`.

   **sass-to-css.js**

   ```js
   const fs = require('fs');
   const path = require('path');
   const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

   // Error when no filename argument provided.
   if (!process.argv[2]) {
     console.log('\x1b[31mERR!\x1b[0m Trailing filename arg must be provided.');
     process.exit(1);
   }

   const fileName = process.argv[2];
   const srcPath = `${path.join('sass', fileName)}.scss`;

   // Check source .scss file exists.
   if (!fs.existsSync(srcPath)) {
     console.log('\x1b[31mERR!\x1b[0m Path cannot be found: %s', srcPath);
     process.exit(1);
   }

   // Path to node-sass executable in node_modules directory.
   const executablePath = path.join('node_modules', '.bin', 'node-sass');

   // Destimation path for resultant .css file.
   const destPath = `${path.join('css', fileName)}.css`;

   // The command to be invoked.
   const cmd = `${executablePath} ${srcPath} ${destPath} -w`;

   // Execute the command.
   execSync(cmd, {
     cwd: process.cwd()
   });
   ```
2. Save `sass-to-css.js` in the root of your projects directory, in the same folder where `package.json` is stored. For example:

   ```
   .
   ├── ...
   ├── node_modules
   │   └── ...
   ├── package.json
   ├── sass
   │   ├── home.scss
   │   └── ...
   └── sass-to-css.js    <--
   ```
3. Then in the `scripts` section of your `package.json` add the following script:

   ```json
   "scripts": {
     "compile": "node sass-to-css"
   }
   ```
4. To invoke the script via your CLI you enter something like the following command(s):

   ```
   $ npm run compile home
   $ npm run compile foo
   $ npm run compile bar
   ```

   **Note**: the last argument provided is the filename, (without the file extension), of the `.scss` file that you want to compile. Namely `home`, `foo`, `bar` in the above example. A space must exist between the `compile` part and the filename/argument.

   The syntax to run the command is not exactly as you requested, but it's close !

**Additional notes:**

1. The pertinent parts of `sass-to-css.js` are:

   - It utilizes nodes [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) to obtain the filename/argument entered via CLI.
   - The paths for the source (`.scss`) and destination (`.css`) files are contructed using nodes [`path.join()`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths).
   - [`child_process.execSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) is utilized to execute the appropriate `node-sass` command.
   - It checks whether the mandatory filename argument has been provided, and also checks whether the resultant filepath for the `.scss` file exists using [`fs.existsSync(path)`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path).
2. `sass-to-css.js` currently utilizes [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (a feature of ES6). If your running an older version of nodejs that doesn't support this sytax then use the ES5 version of the script below instead:

   **ES5 version of sass-to-css.js**

   ```js
   var fs = require('fs');
   var path = require('path');
   var execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

   // Error when no filename argument provided.
   if (!process.argv[2]) {
     console.log('\x1b[31mERR!\x1b[0m Trailing filename arg must be provided.');
     process.exit(1);
   }

   var fileName = process.argv[2];
   var srcPath = path.join('sass', fileName) + '.scss';

   // Check source .scss file exists.
   if (!fs.existsSync(srcPath)) {
     console.log('\x1b[31mERR!\x1b[0m Path cannot be found: %s', srcPath);
     process.exit(1);
   }

   // Path to node-sass executable in node_modules directory.
   var executablePath = path.join('node_modules', '.bin', 'node-sass');

   // Destimation path for resultant .css file.
   var destPath = path.join('css', fileName) + '.css';

   // The command to be invoked.
   var cmd = executablePath + ' ' + srcPath + ' ' + destPath + ' -w';

   // Execute the command.
   execSync(cmd, {
     cwd: process.cwd()
   });
   ```

Comment: No, I do want the -w tag because I have just a lot of pages, so I need the -w tag when individually working on the pages.

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't work when you add the `-w` tag to the `cmd` variable in `sass-to-css.js`? As per updated code in my answer.

Comment: No, I just wanted the -w tag in there